# Having a class be a goog.events.EventHandler and a goog.events.EventTarget

Tags: javascript, dom-events, google-closure-library

I have a view class that listen to events on DOM elements. It also fires events that the controller listens to.

How does that best work with Google Closure's library?

Here's my best shot.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {goog.events.EventHandler}
 * @implements {goog.events.Listenable}
 */
var MyViewClass = function() {
    goog.events.EventHandler.call(this);
    goog.events.EventTarget.call(this);
};
goog.inherits(MyViewClass, goog.events.EventHandler);
goog.object.extend(MyViewClass, goog.events.EventTarget);
```

Is there a better way? My use case seems reasonable. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a class in the Google Closure Library that does a similar thing: [`goog.events.FileDropHandler`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_events_FileDropHandler.html).

It both listens for and fires events. The relevant parts of the [source code](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/local_closure_goog_events_filedrophandler.js.source.html):

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {goog.events.EventTarget}
 */
goog.events.FileDropHandler = function(element, opt_preventDropOutside) {
  goog.events.EventTarget.call(this);
  this.eventHandler_ = new goog.events.EventHandler(this);
};
goog.inherits(goog.events.FileDropHandler, goog.events.EventTarget);

goog.events.FileDropHandler.prototype.disposeInternal = function() {
  goog.events.FileDropHandler.superClass_.disposeInternal.call(this);
  this.eventHandler_.dispose();
};
```

Thus, it extends `goog.events.EventTarget`, but the handler is a different object. This seems to follow a pattern in other classes in the Closure Library as well.

---

I think I would prefer using `registerDisposable` from the `goog.Disposable` superclass instead of overriding `disposeInternal`, but the idea is the same.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {goog.events.EventTarget}
 */
var MyViewClass = function() {
    goog.events.EventTarget.call(this);
    this.handler = new goog.events.EventHandler();
    this.registerDisposable(this.handler);
};
goog.inherits(MyViewClass, goog.events.EventTarget);
```

Answer (score 0):

What your answer describes is preferring composition over inheritance.  It is better to be composed of multiple things instead of inheriting multiple things.  This looks like the correct way to listen to things.

But if you want something that already does this, you should just use goog.ui.Control.

It contains an event handler, and disposes the handler correctly.  Controls can listen to google component type events, and even DOM events.